# Summarise list of lists of vectors at a index in r

Tags: r, nested-lists

So I'm trying to summarize the value of the nested vectors in each list at a certain time. The vectors are seen as values for individuals in discrete time. The list looks like this

```
groups <- 100
size <- 10
workspace <- list()

for (i in 1:groups) {
  workspace[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in 1:size) {
    workspace[[i]][[j]] <- c(1,1,1)
  }
}
```

The value for person j in group i at time 3 is attained with

```
workspace[[i]][[j]][3]
```

The groups are of size 10 and since all values are equal to 1 the sum returned should be 10.

An unsuccessful attempt to summarise the values for group 100 at time 3 would look something like this

```
sum(workspace[[100]][[]][3])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: would you consider converting your nested list into a `data.frame`? it would be substantially easier to do this type of calculation with that structure.

Comment: That made things a lot easier, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick line to loop over every group, extract the third element from each item and sum  it up:

```
lapply(workspace, function(x) sum(sapply(x, "[", 3)))
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 10

[[3]]
[1] 10

[[4]]
[1] 10
...
```

Alternatively, we could use `sapply` to get the output in a vector, with the nth element of the vector corresponding to the nth group:

```
sapply(workspace, function(x) sum(sapply(x, "[", 3)))
  [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 [35] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 [69] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

If you just want the 100th group, we can pass `workspace[[100]]` directly to the inner part:

```
sum(sapply(workspace[[100]], "[", 3))
# [1] 10
```

Hopefully you can generalize from these examples for whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function, which adapts to the structure of your object (a list of list).

```
own_sum <- function(myobject, group, time){
  mylist <- myobject[[group]]
  result <- 0
  for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
    result <- result + mylist[[i]][[time]] 
  }
  return(result)
}

own_sum(biglist = workspace, group = 100, time = 3)
# [1] 10
```